# How to get GPU info for an iOS device via code

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, core-animation, gpu

I am working on iOS app which have some animations, which don't work well in iOS devices with less powerful GPU. I am thinking I should disable animations in devices with less powerful GPUs
Is there any way I could find GPU info via a code...?

Answer (score -2):

You don't get the device GPU information through your code. The alternate way is, with device name, you can play it. Check Apple's [Hardware GPU Information](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html).

Comment: That what I am doing at the moment... but I need to add device name each time when apple gonna release...